# Zend Framework 2 + Doctrine2 - Entities not detected

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Hi i used composer to create the ZF2 skeleton app.
Installed doctrine-module, doctrine-orm-module etc. composer file below:

> `{
>       "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
>       "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
>       "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
>       "keywords": [
>           "framework",
>           "zf2"
>       ],
>       "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
>       "require": {
>           "php": ">=5.3.3",
>           "zendframework/zendframework": "2.2.*",
>       "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.*",
>           "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master",
>           "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
>           "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
>           "bjyoungblood/bjy-profiler": "dev-master",
>           "zendframework/zftool": "dev-master"
>       }
>   }`

Added doctrine config to the module as follows:

> `'doctrine' => array(
>           'driver' => array(
>               __NAMESPACE__.'_entities' => array(
>                   'class' =>'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
>                   //'cache' => 'array',
>                   'paths' => array(
>                       __DIR__ . '/../src/'. __NAMESPACE__ .'/Entity',
>                   )
>               ),
>               'orm_default' => array(
>                   'drivers' => array(
>                       __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_entities'
>                   )
>               ))),`

And i added my entity to:
**module/Application/src/Application/Entity/User.php**

But when i run:
php zf.php orm:info

i get the following message:

> [Exception]
>   You do not have any mapped Doctrine ORM entities
>   according to the current configuration. If you have entities or
>   mapping files you should check your mapping configuration for errors.

If i try

**php zf.php orm:schema-tool:create**

i get:

> No Metadata Classes to process.

How can i get Doctrine to generate my database? What am i doing wrong?

Edit:
Here is the entity code as requested in the comments:

> ```
> <?php
> namespace Application\Entity;
> use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
> /** @ORM\Entity */
> class User {
>     /**
>      * @ORM\Id
>      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
>      * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
>      */
>     protected $id;
>
>     /** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
>     protected $fullName;
> }
> ```

Small update,

i am actually running this inside of a virtual machine. The folder where the files are is mounted from the host. If i copy files to tmp folder, it works just fine. If i run php zf.php orm:info in the mounted folder i get an error.
Virtualisation used is Paralles 8, host OS is OSX, and guest is Debian 7. 
I am working in /media/psf/ mount.

Comment: have you added a namespace in your config file?

Comment: Yep. On top of the file there is namespace Application; Otherwise there is a fatal error ...

Comment: Can you show your entity code ?

Comment: Sure, i added it to the original question.

Comment: Small update, i am actually running this inside of a virtual machine. The folder where the files are is mounted from the host. If i copy files to tmp folder, it works just fine. If i run php zf.php orm:info in the mounted folder i get an error.

Comment: Make sure you have added 'DoctrineModule' and 'DoctrineORMModule' to your application.config.php file!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with outdated parallels tools.
After doing some investigation, i found out there is a ne version of parallels tools available.

Manual update of the tools, and restart of the virtual machine solved the problem. 
There was nothing wrong even with the original code, and it all worked fine after the update. 
I guess there was a bug in parallels, but i did not find any reference about it online.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Downvoting answers that didn't work for you because your problem was caused by something completely different isn't the best thing to do here on SO - just sayin'

Comment: Answers did not bring anything that would go towards solving the problem. The code presented was correct, and they all attempted to solve it all answers were posted after the update to the question was done which states that the code works fine if pasted to a tmp folder.

Comment: Your question is throwing us off a bit: You are primarily describing config and code, and just a tiny piece of info ("small update") about the actual problem. The down-votes feel like punishing those who follow the main drift of your question, and not the hidden problem. My advise for the next time: Update your question in such a way that the real issue get the focus.

Answer (score 2):

The `__NAMESPACE__` directive in your doctrine config must be a problem : your config probably do not use a namespace and so the `__NAMESPACE__` will resolve to the main namespace.

You can try a config like this one :

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        'application_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(
                'module/Application/src/Application/Entity',
            ),
        ),
```

No need to use `__DIR__`, you can use the application root as ZendApplication is chrooted (in `public/index.php` : `chdir(dirname(__DIR__));` ).

Finally, you can also specify the table name for your Entity and the getters/setters for mapped columns :

```
<?php
namespace Application\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/** 
 * @ORM\Entity 
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User {
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** 
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string") 
     */
    protected $fullName;

    /** 
     * @return int 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /** 
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /** 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFullName()
    {
        return $this->fullName;
    }

    /** 
     * @param string $fullname
     */
    public function setFullName($fullname)
    {
        $this->fullName= $fullname;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working. My suspicion is it does not work due to the fact it is a mounted folder. As i provided additional info in the edit.